# Number of bits to represent an integer in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

I have to convert an integer to find how many bits are required to represent that integer.
Let say, integer value is **22**. I know **5 bits** are required to represent this integer.
Is there any attribute in VHDL to do this?
Important: The result should also be an integer, which should represent number of bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no VHDL attribute or function, but you can create a function like:

```
-- Returns number of bits required to represent val in binary vector
function bits_req(val : natural) return natural is
  variable res_v    : natural;  -- Result
  variable remain_v : natural;  -- Remainder used in iteration
begin
  res_v := 0;
  remain_v := val;
  while remain_v > 0 loop  -- Iteration for each bit required
    res_v := res_v + 1;
    remain_v := remain_v / 2;
  end loop;
  return res_v;
end function;
```

However, sometimes a `ceil_log2` function is also useful, since that gives the number of required address bits based on entries in a memory map, and `ceil_log2(val) = bits_req(val - 1)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use the math_real library.  It's not for synthesis, but works great between the architecture and begin statements.

```
use ieee.math_real.all;


constant nbits : natural := integer(ceil(log2(real(n))));
```

I use math_real a lot for in-line generating sin/cos tables... again it's between architecture and begin... again, don't try to use math_real in synthesis.

I've used this in Quartus, ISE, Vivado, Modelsim successfully; it might not be supported by everything out there.

Comment: Your constant statement works for synthesis, as long as it is evaluated compile-time.