# How to calculate the number of bits needed for an std_logic_vector when its size is parametrable?

Tags: type-conversion, vhdl

I have an entity that instanciates a FIFO which depth is a generic:

```
DEPTH_FIFO : natural range 2 to 64 := 3; -- number of vectors in the FIFO
```

I have to declare a counter that could store the index of the FIFO but I need to know which size has to be the counter.

```
signal cnt_FIFO : unsigned(length_cnt_FIFO-1 downto 0);
```

My problem is to find a way to calculate the constant length_cnt_FIFO.

I have tried this :

```
constant length_cnt_FIFO : natural := CEIL(LOG(2, DEPTH_FIFO));
```

with the library `use ieee.MATH_REAL.all;`

but I get problems of type conversion.

Anyone has an idea to make this work, or any other solution ?

Thanks in advance,

SLP

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of bits to represent an integer in VHDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783280/number-of-bits-to-represent-an-integer-in-vhdl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Your `DEPTH_FIFO` is natural, but you have to convert it to a Real to pass it to the logarithmic function.
2. The CEIL function returns a real: you have to convert it back to a natural to store it in a constant of natural type.
3. The parameters of LOG function are real, so passing a literal 2 causes problems because it is handled as an integer. Use e.g. `2.0` instead or the LOG2 function.

This did the trick for me:

```
constant length_cnt_FIFO : natural := natural(CEIL(LOG2(real(DEPTH_FIFO))));
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the following function defined in a utility package I keep handy:

```
function ilog2(val : integer) return integer
is
    constant vec : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) :=
        std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(val, 32));
begin
    for i in vec'left downto vec'right loop
        if (vec(i) = '1') then
            return i;
        end if;
    end loop;
    return -1; -- The number is '0'.
end function ilog2;
```

Comment: This can be used, too. However, the rounding type of this function is "floor", isn't it? To make the function "ceil", appropriate shifting must be added after a '1' bit is met. And then check if the shifted vector is all zeros.